# Node.js - Dynamic list using ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have an array like so for example:

`const arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];`

`arr` could have any length, I'm just using this as an example. How would I go about dynamically adding the `arr` into a list on ejs.

I'm aware I could do this

```
// index.ejs
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><%= item %></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>

// app.js
res.render('index', {
    item: arr[0]
})
```

Which will render only the first item in the array. How would I make it so it ends up like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>bar</li>
            <li>baz</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use array's `forEach` method in ejs the same way you can use it in JavaScript so

```
<ul>
  <% arr.forEach((item) => { %>
    <li><%= item %></li>
  <% }) %>
</ul>
```

will solve your problem.

You should probably add test to check whether the `arr` actually exists so that it won't try to iterate through it if there is no array (array is `undefined`) or its length is zero.
It may happen that you, at some point, send `undefined` value for array to view.

```
res.render('index', { arr: undefined });
```

In such case, if you don't perform that check, your view will crash because there is no `forEach` method of `undefined`.

```
<% if (arr && arr.length) { %>
  <ul>
    <% arr.forEach((item) => { %>
      <li><%= item %></li>
    <% }) %>
  </ul>
<% } %>
```

And you need to pass the whole array to the view for the above code to work.

```
res.render(index, { arr });
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass the array to the view

```
// app.js
res.render('index', {
    arr
})
```

Loop through it

```
<ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {%>
   <li><%= arr[i] %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to map.

```
 //app
 res.render('index',{ arr })
```

map

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <ul>
        <%arr.map( item => {%> 
           <li><%= item%></li>
        <%})%>
    </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```